# IndexError: list index out of range when selecte values in openerp

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

My code:

```
class kho(osv.osv):
    _name = "tt_kho" 
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Mã nguyên liệu ',size=20,required=True), 
        'ten': fields.char('Tên nguyên liệu',size=100,required=True),
        'loai': fields.char('Loại vật liệu',size=100,required=True),
        'soluong':fields.integer('Số lượng hiện có',required=True),
    }
class nguyenlieu(osv.osv):
    _name = "tt_nguyenlieu" 
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.many2one('tt_kho','Mã nguyên liệu',required=True), 
        'ten': fields.char('Tên nguyên liệu',size=100,required=True),
        'loai': fields.char('Loại vật liệu',size=100,required=True),
        'soluong':fields.integer('Số lượng cần',required=True),}
    def onchange_ten(self,cr,uid,ids,name,context=None):
            value={}
            if name:
                record_id=self.pool.get('tt_kho').search(cr,uid,[('name','=',name)],context=context)
                record=self.pool.get('tt_kho').browse(cr,uid,record_id[0],context=context)
                value['ten']=record.ten
            else:
                value['ten']=None
            return {'value':value}
nguyenlieu()
```

My xml file:

```
<record id="nlform" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Nguyên liệu</field>
            <field name="model">tt_nguyenlieu</field> 
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <form>
                        <group col="2">
                            <field name="name" on_change="onchange_ten(name)"/>
                            <field name="ten"/>
                            <field name="loai"/>
                            <field name="soluong"/>
                        </group>
                    </form> 
             </field>
        </record>
```

Here is Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\openerp-8.0rc1\openerp\addons\DoanERP\core.py", line 24, in onchange_ten
record=self.pool.get('tt_kho').browse(cr,uid,record_id[0],context=context)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I select value name on "Nguyên liệu" form ,this error comes.

I added some code and no error show but it looks like it can't get record id from tt_kho .It shows only 'haha' .

```
def onchange_ten(self,cr,uid,ids,name,context=None):
        value={}
        if name:
            record_id=self.pool.get('tt_kho').search(cr,uid,[('name','=',name)],context=context)
            if record_id:
                record=self.pool.get('tt_kho').browse(cr,uid,record_id[0],context=context)
                value['ten']=record.ten
            else:
                value['ten']='haha'
        else:
            value['ten']=None
        return {'value':value}
```

Comment: `record_id` gives empty list that'y you got that error. Check your search criteria it must be at least return 1 id so you can use  `record_id[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odedra is right, but I would like to point out two things:

- be aware that using field name as many2one might cause a lot of trouble - name in odoo is considered as a main field to filter with.
- when you do onchange for many2one field, you will not get a value, which can be searched with - use _logger.warn(name) to see, what value did you get - you will get an id instead of a name (just checked that), so you shoud skip the line with search and use record=self.pool.get('tt_kho').browse(cr,uid,**name**,context=context) instead

That should do the trick - make us know, if that doesn't work either.